# Conditions on a metric space such that the closed $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of a compact set is compact

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $K$ a compact subset of $X$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. We define the closed $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $K$ as
$$
K_\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid d(x, K) := \inf_{y\in K} d(x, y) \le \varepsilon\}.
$$

Could you elaborate on some conditions (locally compact, separable,...) on $X$ such that $K_\varepsilon$ is compact? Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true iff every closed bounded subset of $X$ is compact (such a metric space is sometimes called *Heine-Borel* or *proper*).  For sufficiency, just note that if $K$ is compact then $K_\epsilon$ is closed and bounded (for closedness, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $K_\epsilon$ then for any $\epsilon'>\epsilon$ there is $(y_n)$ in $K$ with $d(x_n,y_n)<\epsilon'$ for each $n$, and then by compactness of $K$ you can pass to a subsequence and assume $(y_n)$ converges).  Conversely, taking $K$ to be a single point, your condition implies that closed balls in $X$ are compact.  Any closed bounded subset of $X$ is contained in a closed ball, and thus is also compact.

(Note that no purely topological conditions besides compactness itself are sufficient to guarantee the Heine-Borel property.  Indeed, if $X$ is any non-compact metrizable space, then just equip $X$ with a bounded metric, and then $X$ is not Heine-Borel with that metric.)